# How to return the latest object inserted in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to retrieve the latest inserted object from my model `Reading` by its field `reading`.

I'm trying like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_config(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reading = Reading.objects.latest('reading')
        print reading
        #reading = 10    

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(str(reading)), content_type="application/json")
    return render(request, 'web/home.html')
```

And this is my model:

```
from django.db import models
...
class Reading(models.Model):
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource)
    reading = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField('date', auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s | %s' % (self.resource.urn, self.reading)
```

The problem is that I'm getting the `__unicode__` returns regardless of what I'm asking in my `views` to be returned.

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: But your view *is* asking for the `__unicode__`. It's explicitly calling `str` on the object.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, I'm new to python+django. Could you please explain ?

Comment: `reading` is the object, you're calling `str` on it, that uses the code to convert it to a string, which is the `__unicode__` method. If you don't want the string representation of the object, don't call `str` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output the field value of the instance then pass this field to the `dumps()` instead of the whole object:

```
json.dumps(str(reading.reading))
```

You can also omit the `str()` call if you want to return a number instead of a string:

```
json.dumps(reading.reading)
```

Comment: Thanks @cataravan, my mistake was that I assume that `reading = Reading.objects.latest('reading')` would return a value and not the object. Thank you!